# Switch Statement returns incorrect results

Tags: php, switch-statement

Halo! I am not sure where I am going wrong in my switch statement! Here's what I want my code to do:

If all three variables are empty, then I want nothing to happen. However, if not, then I want to see which ones are empty and which ones are not and perform different tasks based on their state.

If they're not empty then I want to add a string before the variable. If they're empty, then I want to add a string stating "..PLEASE PROVIDE INFORMATION".

With the current hard coded variables, it should return:

```
Airline Name: United 
Flight Number: 262
Departure Airport: PLEASE PROVIDE DEPARTURE AIRPORT
```

but it returns:

```
Airline Name: PLEASE PROVIDE AIRLINE NAME
Flight Number: PLEASE PROVIDE FLIGHT NUMBER
Departure Airport: PLEASE PROVIDE DEPARTURE AIRPORT
```

Code:

```
$airline_name = "United";
$flight_number = 262;
$departure_airport = "";

function airport($one, $two, $three) {

if ($one =="" && $two =="" && $three =="") {
} else {
    switch(true) {
        case !empty($one):
        $one = "Airline Name: $one<br>";
        case empty($one):
        $one = "Airline Name: PLEASE PROVIDE AIRLINE NAME<br>";
        case !empty($two):
        $two = "Flight Number: $two<br>";
        case empty($two):
        $two = "Flight Number: PLEASE PROVIDE FLIGHT NUMBER<br>";
        case !empty($three):
        $three = "Departure Airport: $three<br>";
        case empty($three):
        $three = "Departure Airport: PLEASE PROVIDE DEPARTURE AIRPORT<br>";
    }

    }
echo $one, $two, $three;
}

airport($airline_name,$flight_number,$departure_airport);

?>
```

Comment: RTM http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.switch.php it's all in there. Your syntax is `break`ing. ;-)

Comment: you need a break statement after each test or before the next case

Comment: Why use a switch, you aren't testing the same variable? Did you write `isempty`? Also why `$one =="" && $two =="" && $three ==""` and then do nothing but use the else? Just test the inverse.

Comment: Thanks @jeff. However, I don't want it to break. I want to go through each of the cases so that all three variables can be properly tested.

Comment: @Fred-ii- and @chris85 I forgot to change those function names from `isempty()` to `empty`. my bad. However, still getting the same results.

Comment: Don't use `switch` the behavior you want isn't what it was designed for. `In many occasions, you may want to compare the same variable (or expression) with many different values, and execute a different piece of code depending on which value it equals to. This is exactly what the switch statement is for.`

Comment: I for one am trying to think of another way if you're not wanting to `break` your case, because that's how `switch/case` works, it won't work without it. Edit: Chris' answer looks promising as I too was thinking "ternary".

Comment: @Fred-ii- Wouldn't the switch/case simply move onto the next case if there's no break? Isn't that another example of a fall-through?

Comment: Take a look at this demo, https://eval.in/490060.

Comment: no, that isn't how it works. You have a few answers below. I personally like Chris' answer, but you can try the other one also. edit: and it seems you have. 2nd edit: and you unaccepted. Ok.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The behavior you want would be achieved with an `if else`, or the ternary operator (which is pretty much just a short hand way of writing an `if/else`). Here's a rough untested example.

```
function airport($one, $two, $three) {
   if ( !empty($one) || !empty($two) || !empty($three) ) {
         $one = !empty($one) ? "Airline Name: $one<br>" :"Airline Name: PLEASE PROVIDE AIRLINE NAME<br>";
         $two = !empty($two) ? "Flight Number: $two<br>" : "Flight Number: PLEASE PROVIDE FLIGHT NUMBER<br>";
         $three = !empty($three) ? "Departure Airport: $three<br>" : "Departure Airport: PLEASE PROVIDE DEPARTURE AIRPORT<br>";
   }
   echo $one, $two, $three;
}
airport($airline_name,$flight_number,$departure_airport);
```

As to why your `switch` doesn't perform as you expect, per the manual:

> Only when a case statement is found with a value that matches the value of the switch expression does PHP begin to execute the statements. **PHP continues to execute the statements until the end of the switch block, or the first time it sees a break statement.** If you don't write a break statement at the end of a case's statement list, PHP will go on executing the statements of the following case.

-http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.switch.php

Comment: I was going to mention a ternary; good show. Let's see what the OP has to say ;-)

Comment: The OP went with the other one, but all is not lost here. I'll be saving this in my collection and is a good addition to the question. Without testing this, I can tell it would have worked.

Comment: @Fred-ii- maybe adding quote will make answer better and explain current issue a bit more. I think that's all I could add to it.. Aha and a typo hah knew I would miss something there.. Thanks.

Comment: Remove your `if` condition at the top, it's going to give you wrong result based on the input OP has.

Comment: Yeah, I just noticed that now. Remove the `if ( !empty($one) && !empty($two) && !empty($three) ) {` and its closing brace `}`.

Comment: Think making it an `or` should suffice, so if any one of them is populated it will enter.

Comment: Lol, yeah that `||` fixed it instead of `&&`. The `if()` can stay. But it's not needed though. It gives the same result. That's what the ternary does ;-)

Comment: Thanks @TareqMahmood.

Comment: Also, I would reduce the code like this `$one = "Airline Name: ". ($one ? $one : 'PLEASE PROVIDE AIRLINE NAME') . "<br>"` (Or even this : `$one = "Airline Name: ". ($one ?: 'PLEASE PROVIDE AIRLINE NAME') . "<br>"`)

Comment: HOLY SMOKES. You guys are beasts. the code now works. I've never seen the ternary in action so this is a first for me too.. It's gonna take some time to digest this. I still have some doubts though that I need to test out myself. I shall be back with some additional questions in a moment!

Comment: We try @GovindRai - and to help everyone in the process ;-) wait till you get a load of "nested" ternaries. Those are rather special.

Comment: @GovindRai You can read more about the operator here, http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php#language.operators.comparison.ternary

Comment: @chris85 Why can't you remove the `if` block at all? Think now what are you going to print when every input is `""`.

Comment: @TareqMahmood don't know the intended result. This will act as previous code acted (now that it is corrected). OP can add `else` if all three are empty.

Comment: @GovindRai *"the code now works"* --- *"I shall be back with some additional questions in a moment!"* - If Chris' answer works for you, then you should mark it as solved. Asking more questions later on, isn't how it works here, unless Chris wants to wait for you and your other questions, that's entirely up to him. Yet, I feel the question should be marked as solved.

Comment: @Fred-ii- I gotcha :). It's just that in my head the question was not yet resolved, and knowing I had your attention I didn't want to lose your help! However, after going through some more debugging and coming back and rereading the answers, I found the answer to my problem. :D `If you don't write a break statement at the end of a case's statement list, PHP will go on executing the statements of the following case.` That one line was the cause of my woes, but that's one hell of a good interesting thing to now know! Thank you!

Comment: @GovindRai I always love a happy ending ;-) I'm glad to hear that you've resolved it and that Chris provided you with some additional knowledge. Ternary operators can be even more complex than this, *cheers* and Happy Holidays.

Answer (score 1):

There are two issues here.
First, as pointed out in the comments, your switch statement doesn't have any `break`s.

Second, a switch statement can only have 1 result. So once it finds its first match, which will happen either when $one is empty or isn't empty, it will end the statement.

In this case, I would just use a series `if` statements instead:

```
    <?php

    $airline_name = "United";
    $flight_number = 262;
    $departure_airport = "";

    function airport($one, $two, $three) {

    if(!empty($one)){
        $one = "Airline Name: $one<br>";
    } else {
        $one = "Airline Name: PLEASE PROVIDE AIRLINE NAME<br>";
    }

    if(!empty($two)){
        $two = "Flight Number: $two<br>";
    } else {
        $two = "Flight Number: PLEASE PROVIDE AIRLINE NAME<br>";
    }

    if(!empty($three)){
        $three = "Departure Airport: $three<br>";
    } else {
        $three = "Departure Airport: PLEASE PROVIDE AIRLINE NAME<br>";
    }

    echo $one, $two, $three;
    }

    airport($airline_name,$flight_number,$departure_airport);

    ?>
```

EDIT
In response to your comment, take this simple example here, if you run it you'll see that the code only echos out 'first' even though all three cases are the same.

```
<?php
$a = 1;
switch ($a) {
    case 1:
        echo 'first';
        break;
    case 1:
        echo 'second';
        break;
    case 1:
        echo 'third';
        break;

}
?>
```

Comment: Okay, the code definitely works and solves the problem of what I want to do. However, even in my original code the switch statements do alter the value of all three variables, so are you sure a switch statement can only have 1 result?

Comment: Yes, a switch statement 'jumps' out once a first match is found. See updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Your syntax is wrong
Switch statements are like this...

```
switch ($some_var) {
    case 'Peter':   // if $some_var has value 'Peter'
        # code...   // this line executes if it is true, else breaks and loops through other cases until it finds right val
        break;

    default:
        # code... // default code to be executed if case val isn't found
        break;
}
```

And one question? Why you are using boolean to switch values ?

Comment: Thanks @MilosM. I see. Okay so I realize that switch is not what I should be using to solve a problem like this. Nonetheless, to further understand,  is the problem because I'm using boolean to switch values? Is that now allowed? Could you clarify where the code is going wrong?

Comment: There is already a answer from @chris85
That code seems legit. Try it.

Answer (score 0):

You can't use switch statement this way, what you are doing now is walking through all cases regardless your condition for example if you swap the first case with the second one the output will be 'United'. That is because you need to put break after each case so when find he right choice break the loop. you can use if else instead and would look simpler and smaller

first put the default value as empty

```
<?php

$airline_name = "United";
$flight_number = 262;
$departure_airport = "";

function airport($one, $two, $three) {

if ($one =="" && $two =="" && $three =="") {
} 

    else
    {
        if ($one == '')
            $one= "PLEASE PROVIDE AIRLINE NAME<br>";
        if ($two == '')
            $two= "PLEASE PROVIDE FLIGHT NUMBER<br>";
        if ($three == '')
            $three = "PLEASE PROVIDE DEPARTURE AIRPORT<br>";

        $x1= "Airline Name: ".$one;
        $x2= "Flight Number: ".$two;
        $x3= "Departure Airport:".$three;
    }



echo $x1, $x2, $x3;
}

airport($airline_name,$flight_number,$departure_airport);

?>
```