# Switch/Case without a `break`, doesn't check the cases properly

Tags: php, switch-statement

I'm having trouble with a switch case conidtion.

Why in the following scenario:

```
$category = "A";
$offer = "none";
$discount = "none";
```

For the following code:

```
switch (TRUE) {

case ($category == 'A') : / #1

    $msg = "hello"; 

case ($offer == 'special') : / #2

        $id = "123"; 

case ($discount == '50D') : / #3

        $id = "999";


break;

echo $id;

}
```

I get output of `999` for `id`, even though `#2` and `#3` are not fullfilled?

**EDIT:**

Cases such as `$offer == 'special'` are private cases of the general case which is `$category == 'A'`.
That's why I want the function to go in this order. 
if switch/case is not appropriate, what shall I use?

Comment: why all the downvotes? isn't that how the function should work?

Comment: I think that's because people don't clearly understand what the problem is.

Comment: Don't start from the middle. Start from the beginning when describing your problem.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Multiple Cases in Switch:](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/68578/multiple-cases-in-switch)

Comment: Read more about the PHP [switch statement](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.switch.php). This is how it was designed to work, 40 years ago, in `C`; `PHP` and a lot of other languages copied the behaviour of `switch` statement from `C`.

Comment: Use, conditionals, not a `switch`. Specifically, `PHP continues to execute the statements until the end of the switch block, or the first time it sees a break statement. If you don't write a break statement at the end of a case's statement list, PHP will go on executing the statements of the following case`. - http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.switch.php

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Switch Statement returns incorrect results](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34446189/switch-statement-returns-incorrect-results)

Comment: @chris85 do you mean "IF" condition? I got into a mess with them in [this thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34566942/how-to-consolidate-various-if-conditions-into-a-final-result), maybe you can recommend something over there?

Comment: Let's just go with your current thread here. There's a lot happening in that other thread if `$offer == 'special'` and `$discount == '50D'` what should `$id` be?

Comment: @chris85 `999`, the idea is that `special` is a private case of `category A` and `50D` is a private case of `special`

Comment: Oh so if a and special and 50d set `999` if just special set `123` and if neither just leave the message?

Comment: small correction: `a+special+50=999`,`a+special=123`,only `A`= just message / do nothing. and I plan to have a category such as `B` with it's own set of cases.

Comment: Take a look at the updated answer below. I think that should give you a starting point.

Comment: I've removed my answer and moved it to your other thread. @Barmar answered the question of why the `switch` doesn't work, which is a separate question than your other thread.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Once `switch` finds a matching `case`, it just executes all the remaining code until it gets to a `break` statement. None of the following `case` expressions are tested, so you can't have dependencies like this. To implement sub-cases, you should use nested `switch` or `if` statements.

```
switch ($category) {
case 'A':
    $msg = 'hello';
    if ($offer == 'special') {
        $id = '123';
    } elseif ($discount == '50D') {
        $id = '999';
    }
    break;
...
}
echo $id;
```

The fallthrough feature of `case` without `break` is most often used when you have two cases that should do exactly the same thing. So the first one has an empty code with no break, and it just falls through.

```
switch ($val) {
case 'AAA':
case 'bbb':
    // some code
    break;
...
}
```

It can also be used when two cases are similar, but one of them needs some extra code run first:

```
switch ($val) {
case 'xxx':
    echo 'xxx is obsolete, please switch to yyy';
case 'yyy':
    // more code
    break;
...
}
```

Comment: alright, so in what instance would anyone would ever want to use a `switch` without `break` between two different cases, if all other cases don't mean anything?

Comment: One example `case 'A': case 'a':`. So both capital and lowercase fall into same group.

Comment: @rockyraw I've added some examples where fallthrough might be used.

Answer (score 0):

This is how a switch-case statement works. It goes through all the `case`es once one condition was met, as long as there is no break. You can read up on it in the manual here: [PHP switch](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.switch.php).

If you want to stop the execution of the switch at the end of an case, just add a `break;` statement.

Comment: I don't want to stop the execution. Since the other cases such as `$offer == 'special'` are private cases of the general case which is `$category == 'A'`

Comment: It doesn't test the other cases when it falls through. Once it finds a matching case, it just executes everything until it gets to `break`.

Comment: What's that *"private cases"*? Use an inner `switch` or `if` statements if you want to check the values of `$offer` and `$discount` only when `$category` matches.

Comment: I was advised to use switch/case in [my original thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34566942/how-to-consolidate-various-if-conditions-into-a-final-result), so what do you recommend considering that other thread?

Comment: @rockyraw IMHO, that style of using `switch` is perverse. It works, but it's confusing.

Comment: what would be the best practice to achieve the goal of my original thread? using IF conditions also caused me some mess.

Comment: @rockyraw When you have a "global" condition that is a pre condition, then why don't use create code block that is only executed if that condition is true, and then put the switch (or more ifs) inside of it? This does not sound like mess to me, but rather like a reasonable approach